# recovery stopping before commit of transaction- Postgres 11 PITR

Tags: postgresql, backup, recovery

I am trying for PITR on a duplicate node. Here are the steps I am following.

1. Start backup on source node.

```
select pg_start_backup('backup')
```

2. Copy all the files on destination node using these rsync commands on the destination node:

```
rsync  -av sourcedb:/TPINFO01/wal_archive/ /TPINFO01/wal_archive
rsync --delete -av sourcedb:/TPINFO01/datadg/tablespace/ /TPINFO01/datadg/tablespace
rsync --delete -av sourcedb:/TPINFO01/datadg/data/ /TPINFO01/datadg/data --exclude 'pg_log' --exclude 'pg_replslot' --exclude 'postgresql.conf' --exclude 'recovery.conf'
```

3. Stop the backup on source node

```
select pg_stop_backup();
```

4. Through crontab, keep copying the WAL files from the source DB every min. There is continuous WAL archiving enabled on source DB.

```
* * * 08 * /home/postgres/rsync_wal.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

rsync_wal.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

rsync -av sourcedb:/TPINFO01/wal_archive/ /TPINFO01/wal_archive
```

5. On next day, I create `recovery.conf` on targetdb as follows:

```
recovery_target_time = '2021-08-16 02:00:00 JST'
recovery_target_action = 'pause'
recovery_target_inclusive = 'false'
restore_command = 'rsync -a /TPINFO01/wal_archive/%f %p'
```

6. It restores the files but stops with the following error:

```
2021-08-16 16:33:52.853 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,1,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"database system was interrupted while in recovery at log time 2021-08-16 02:27:59 JST",,"If this has occurred more than once some data might be corrupted and you might need to choose an earlier recovery target.",,,,,,,""
2021-08-16 16:33:53.023 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,2,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"starting point-in-time recovery to 2021-08-16 02:00:00+09",,,,,,,,,""
2021-08-16 16:33:53.120 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,3,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,,0,LOG,00000,"restored log file ""0000000100009928000000A7"" from archive",,,,,,,,,""
2021-08-16 16:33:53.144 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,4,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,1/0,0,LOG,00000,"redo starts at 9928/A73B0DA8",,,,,,,,,""
2021-08-16 16:33:53.145 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,5,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,1/0,0,LOG,00000,"recovery stopping before commit of transaction 74385349, time 2021-08-16 02:30:01.469553+09",,,,,,,,,""
2021-08-16 16:33:53.145 JST,,,3608,,611a14e0.e18,6,,2021-08-16 16:33:52 JST,1/0,0,FATAL,XX000,"requested recovery stop point is before consistent recovery point",,,,,,,,,""
```

What is wrong here? How can the DB on the target node be corrupted when it wasn't even started? Am I missing some step?

This is what the backup file looks like

```
START WAL LOCATION: 9928/9D000028 (file 00000001000099280000009D)
STOP WAL LOCATION: 9928/9D000168 (file 00000001000099280000009D)
CHECKPOINT LOCATION: 9928/9D000098
BACKUP METHOD: pg_start_backup
BACKUP FROM: master
START TIME: 2021-08-15 21:58:00 JST
LABEL: backup
START TIMELINE: 1
STOP TIME: 2021-08-15 22:03:44 JST
STOP TIMELINE: 1
```

Comment: Whatever the reason, the error indicates that the WAL segment that got archived during `pg_stop_backup()` (and that contains the backup end record) didn't make it to the standby.

Comment: That worked, I tried to take the backup again. Ensured that the crontab script to rsync the  WAL files was running simultaneously and then followed the same steps as above and it worked this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Laurenz Albe, I was missing the WAL file during the `pg_stop_backup()`.

I repeated the steps above, with the only difference that the cronjob to copy the WAL segments from source to target DB was running continuously during the backup as well so as to ensure that no WAL segments were missed.

It worked this way and I could do PITR for my desired time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your WAL archiving is not working reliably.

Rather than using `rsync` from a cron job to copy WAL segments, which seems to miss segments occasionally, use PostgreSQL's `archive_command` to archive WAL segments. Then PostgreSQL will make sure that all segments are archived.

Comment: The `archive_command` is in place on the source DB which is sending the files from `pg_wal` folder to `wal_archive`, from where I am picking those segments. Since it is a PROD DB, I can't change the config file for my testing, which is why I copied the whole backup on a separate DB and had been trying PITR on that one.

Comment: If you have an `archive_command` anyway, why the cron job? Put the `rsync` into the `archive_command`, just like you do in the `restore_command`.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your comment, but I can't make changes on the source DB's `archive_command` and add `rsync` to get the files on this target server, as the source DB is PROD environment and changes are not allowed. I can only make a copy of it. The cron job is on the target server. Also, the WAL segments sent to the `wal_archive` folder on the source DB are removed by a script every 2 mins and sent to a backup server. So that is most likely the reason my rsync missed some of the WAL segments.

Comment: Yes, that must be the case. Since it seems that you are only experimenting rather than trying to set up a reliable operation, I'll stop worrying.